# Get Decryption key for aes 128 cbc without password for m3u8 video stream in Python

Tags: python, encryption, openssl, aes, m3u8

I have a video.ts file compiled by adding together a video stream in m3u8 format. I am trying to decrypt the video using the below statement.

```
   subprocess.run(['openssl', 'aes-128-cbc','-K','[KEY]','-iv','[IV]','-nosalt','-in' ,'video.ts','- 
   out','video_name.mp4'])
```

Although, I have the value for [IV] but not the [KEY]. I do have a link given as 'uri' in the following format but it runs into error when I open it using the browser.

```
 'key': {'method': 'AES-128',
  'uri': 'https://...',
  'iv': '.....'}
```

Is there some way to use this info to extract the key for decryption.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using AES-128 encryption on a HLS stream.

You can check this by looking in the M3U8 file itself - you should see some information including the following settings:

EXT-X-KEY:

- METHOD: AES-128
- URI: the URL of a key server
- KEYFORMAT: identity (or no KEYFORMAT specified)

An example below (from: https://docs.unified-streaming.com/documentation/drm/hls.html - you can see examples from other packagers etc also):

```js
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:1
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://license-server/video.key"
#EXTINF:4, no desc
video-audio=65000-video=236000-0.ts
```

From what you have shown above it looks like you need to simply get the key itself from the ''uri': 'https://...'' URI in your example and then use it in your decryption.

Comment: Actually, opening the URI gives this error --> "Server Error in '/' Application"

Comment: @AbhiGupta - it sounds like whatever server is meant to be providing the key is not set up to do this correctly. I think you'll have to speak to the owner or developer for that server. Alternatively, if you actually know they key yourself you can server it from your own server.